# How to generate sequence and UML class diagram in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have started working on a new C# project in Visual Studio Professional 2022 and wanted to create a sequence diagram and UML class diagram for the entire project.

Is there a way to do that using Visual Studio Professional 2022?

Is there a third-party tool I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to collect a sequence of method calls from your application.

And there is RFClassGraph add-in for it that creates a class relationship diagram from the sequence:
https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/documentation/api.html